# R.java file is not updated in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have a problem with Android Studio 0.4.2. The R.java is not updated when I create or update layout resources files.
I have seen there was an issue on earlier versions of Android Studio that deals with that problem but it doesn't to work anymore for Android Studio 0.4.2.
Android Studio doesn't seems to log any error message when I build the module.
I have also seen similar questions but mainly for Eclipse and I didn't find answers for Android Studio 0.4.2.
Furthermore, I imported this module into Android Studio From an ADT Eclipse project.

Comment: To compare, I created a new Project from Android Studio, not an imported one. The structure between an imported and a new one are very different.
I tried to use the new one to resume my coding but I cannot create a new test source folder for the Android module of the new project...

Comment: Try updating Android Studio. 0.4.2 is rather old.

Comment: I did nothing really changed. Do you know how to add a source folder on a native Android Studio Android application project? In the module Settings I can't see sources folders

Comment: You can set source directories in the build files. There's no UI for it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you always have to  `Clean` your Project and `Re-build` the Project

For the resources to appear in your code.

*Don't ask why or who, they don't like it ;)*

Comment: no, you can only right click on your project and select synch will appear all new resources. but this is another thing. R file is not showing ids from layout xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Closing Android studio completely and re-opening it again seems to work for me sometimes.

Although this is not specific for 0.4.2, I have been using this technique since 0.6.* up to current version (0.8.* as of today)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning my project imported from Eclipse with ADT, I finally noticed that the R file in the gen directory (inherited from the Eclipse projet and configured as generation directory in the Android Facet of my Android Studio Projet), is just a stub and doesn't contains the code available at the compile time.

In fact, the generated elements are available in the code suggestions when coding and the Android Studio module compiles well.
I concluded from it that it's the behavior of Android Studio when importing Eclipse ADT projects.

I hope am i not wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If what @MDMalik said doesn't work, try removing the project from the workspace and importing it again.

Also, check to see if there are any problems in your layout xml files. An error in those sometimes stops R.java from being generated!